# Backward compatibility for biblatex custom style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

In a current project involving multiple other people working on the same latex base, I am using a custom biblatex bibliography style based on the standard style. Within it, I want to have

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[article]{eprint=false}
```

This works as intended e.g. on MiKTex 21.1 or texlive2020.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with texlive2017, which is installed on computers used by several other people (and atm I cannot update the version there).
I figured I could get the same behaviour with these older versions by also adding

```
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{eprint}[true]{\settoggle{bbx:eprint}{#1}}
```

Unfortunately, this breaks with the newer versions, as the option `eprint` is already defined.

Can I build in a switch that either checks for the existence of the (type) option or the biblatex version? If so, how? I would prefer to keep using the standard style and not having to c&p everything from there.
I currently need to provide this backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` type options are generated via `keyval` with set name `blx@opt@typ`. So we just need a test to see if the `keyval` option with the name `eprint` is defined in that set.

The test `\blx@kv@ifkeyundef` we use here is defined in newer versions of `biblatex` (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/991), but might not be available in older versions, so we copy its definition explicitly.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\blx@kv@ifkeyundef}[2]{%
  \ifcsundef{KV@#1@#2}}

% {<scope>}{<option name>}
\newcommand*{\IfBiblatexOptionUndef}[2]{%
  \blx@kv@ifkeyundef{blx@opt@#1}{#2}}

\IfBiblatexOptionUndef{typ}{eprint}
  {\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{eprint}[true]{\settoggle{bbx:eprint}{#1}}}
  {}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The set names are as follows

| Option scope | Scope name |
| --- | --- |
| Load-time | `ldt` |
| Global | `pre` |
| Type | `typ` |
| Entry | `ent` |
| Namelist | `namelist` |
| Name | `name` |
| Namepart | `namepart` |